# Relatively scale an object collection in 3D space

Tags: algorithm, math, 3d, scale, transformation

Given a group of 3D models spatially arranged in a specific formation, how do I scale them while preserving the relative distances between each other?

Case in point: I have 10 meshes. Six of them are arranged to form a closed square room. The remaining 4 are pieces of furniture placed at appropriate locations inside it. All meshes have a scale of 1.0. I wish to increase it to, say 2.0.

Comment: You need to be more specific... When you say "relative distance", do you mean the relative distance from the two nearest opposing faces, or the relative distance between the "elected centre" of any two objects?

Comment: Apologies for the lack of clarity. I believe it's the latter, so that they don't end up clipping into each other.

Comment: You need to get even more specific. I assume you want something like 1) scale all individual objects wrt. their local origin and then 2) scale everything (i.e. object positions) wrt. global origin.

Comment: And when you say "*relative* distance" do you mean that you want to preserve the condition that, say, the distance from object A to object B is twice the distance from A to C?

Comment: Updated the question with a bit more info. @Beta, yes. To put it very simply, I want the furniture to stay in the same position relative to the room's interior.

Comment: So just scale everything. Scale each object individually, and the positions of the "elected centers" (or whatever) of the objects.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

*I am not a mathematician, so I'm going to use the most basic terminology I know how to explain the procedure. You may even find the simplicity of the terminology I use easier to understand than mathematic "jargon"*

You need to use the nominal centre points of all objects in the formation to determine the exact *Formation Centre* (this will be, of course, a 3D Vector consisting of an X, Y and Z value)...

**Object Total** = The total number of objects within your "formation"

- Cycle through all objects in your formation

  - For each **object** (to calculate *Axis Total*)

    - Add the X co-ordinates together (gives us **Axis Total X**)
    - Add the Y co-ordinates together (gives us **Axis Total Y**)
    - Add the Z co-ordinates together (gives us **Axis Total Z**)
  - For each **Axis Total** *axis* (to calculate **Formation Centre**)

    - **Formation Centre X** = **Axis Total X** divided by **Object Total**
    - **Formation Centre Y** = **Axis Total Y** divided by **Object Total**
    - **Formation Centre Z** = **Axis Total Z** divided by **Object Total**

The three values you now have constitute the **Formation Centre** (as a 3D vector).

**NOTE**: *If you are arranging your objects based on a pre-defined fixed point in 3D space (0, 0, 0 for example) you don't need to do the above calculation, as your **Formation Centre** will be that fixed point.*

- for each object

  - Calculate the *Distance* of each axis (**Distance X**, **Distance Y** and **Distance Z**) of the *Object Centre* from the according axis of *Formation Centre*...

    - **Distance X** = **Formation Centre X** - **Object Position X**
    - **Distance Y** = **Formation Centre Y** - **Object Position Y**
    - **Distance Z** = **Formation Centre Z** - **Object Position Z**
  - Scale the object by your desired **Scale Factor**
  - Set the X, Y and Z *Position* values to their current value plus the distance value of the same axis multiplied by the scale...

    - **Position X** = **Position X** + (**Distance X** * **Scale Factor**)
    - **Position Y** = **Position Y** + (**Distance Y** * **Scale Factor**)
    - **Position Z** = **Position Z** + (**Distance Z** * **Scale Factor**)

If you've done this correctly, your objects have now been scaled, still retain their formation, but have moved relative to the **Formation Centre** and **Scale Factor**. Simply put: occlusion between these objects can no longer occur as their *Positions* have scaled along with their *Dimensions*.

Comment: It's also worth pointing out that this is pretty-much exactly how the objects themselves are scaled individually! The verticies are just repositioned relative to their central point!

Comment: @shadeMe You're very welcome! This is the sort of thing best demonstrated with a video, though, and your question has inspired me to put together a full video demonstration of this process (step-by-step)

Answer (score 1):

To really answer this, we still need a bit more information about the format of your data and how you're applying transformations.  But here's a guess: 
Your objects are most likely represented as collection of polygons which are themselves represented as a collection of points relative to some 'root point' such as the center of the object or a bottom corner.  When you place the object somewhere, like a room, you can do so by applying a sequence of matrix multiplications to the points that represent the object.  A single matrix multiply can usually do the whole transformation, but it makes more sense to us if we compose a sequence of transformations that do intuitive things.  For example, you would usually

1. **Scale** the object to be the size you want.
2. **Rotate** the object to be oriented the way you want.
3. **Translate** the object to be where you want.

All of these transformations happen relative to the 'root point' of the object and their order makes a big difference.  If you translate and then scale or rotate, the scale and rotate will happen relative to the newly translated center.

So, if you have placed objects in a room, and **[0,0,0]** of your coordinate system happens to be in the center of the room, if you scale all of the transformed points of those objects, they will all grow/shrink and push outward/inward from **[0,0,0]**.  Since that's not what you want, you must first change the origin by translating the object, then scale, then change the origin back to where it was.

If I have two points: **[3,0,0]** and **[4,0,0]** and I want to scale them so that the distance between them is **2** instead of **1**, if I just multiply (scale) by **2**, I get **[6,0,0]** and **[8,0,0]**.  There's a distance of **2** between them now, but they both moved.  If I want the first point to stay put, then I first translate by **[-3,0,0]**, then I scale by **2**, then I translate by **[3,0,0]** and I have what I wanted.  If, instead, I want the center of those two points to remain the same, then I translate by **[(+/-)3.5,0,0]**.

It falls on you to decide which points of the objects should not move.  Then you move that point to the origin before scaling.  Then you move it back afterward.  Since you don't want your objects to push through the floor, you'll probably pick a point on the ground (or whatever surface they're attached to).  If you have one object resting on another (books on a desk) then those objects should probably use the same reference point.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to explain the transformation process to me!